# CSS doesn't work if I include the HTML from a PHP

Tags: php, html, css

This is the situation.

I have three files:

1. index.html
2. completeupdate.html
3. chronus.php

(1) and (2) are almost identical, (2) was modified to remove a button and modify some body text.
What Happens is that I call (2) from (3).

So on (1) and (2) if they are called directly from the browser the CSS works fine, but as (2) is being called from inside (3) the CSS just doesn't work.

This is how the PHP script:

```
<?php
    //GETTING SEVER DATE
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    //UPDATES THE LOG
    function logUpdate()
    {       
        //bunch of unharmfull and uninteresting code
    }

    logUpdate();
    include("../jude/updatecomplete.html");
?>
```

**UPDATE-1**

Here is the (1):[image]

Here is the (2): [image]

**UPDATE-1-END**

**UPDATE-2**

Code for (1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Judith Lars</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script:400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/config.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="homepage">

        <!-- Header Wrapper -->
            <div id="header-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">

                            <!-- Header -->
                                <header id="header">

                                    <!-- Logo -->
                                        <div id="logo">
                                            <h1><a href="#" id="logo">Judith Lars</a></h1>
                                            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
                                        </div>
                                </header>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Banner Wrapper -->
            <div id="banner-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">

                            <!-- Banner -->
                                <div id="banner" class="box">

                                    <div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="7u">
                                                <h2>Nam rutrum est gravida, adipiscing ipsum vel, viverra nisl.</h2>
                                                <p>Donec viverra nisi in urna vestibulum, sed pharetra risus.</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="5u">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="../php/chronus.php" class="button big fa fa-arrow-circle-right">Update it now.</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Footer Wrapper -->
            <div id="footer-wrapper">
                <footer id="footer" class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="3u">

                            <!-- Contact -->
                                <section class="widget-contact last">
                                    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter solo"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook solo"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p>Av. João, 1234<br />
                                    São Paulo, São Paulo<br />
                                    (11) 1234-1234</p>
                                </section>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <div id="copyright">
                                &copy; App4U Sistemas de Informação Ltda. All rights reserved. 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Code for (2):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Judith Lars</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script:400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/config.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.app4u.com.br/labs/royalib/verti/css/skel-noscript.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.app4u.com.br/labs/royalib/verti/css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.app4u.com.br/labs/royalib/verti/css/style-desktop.css" />
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="homepage">

        <!-- Header Wrapper -->
            <div id="header-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">

                            <!-- Header -->
                                <header id="header">

                                    <!-- Logo -->
                                        <div id="logo">
                                            <h1><a href="#" id="logo">Judith Lars</a></h1>
                                            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
                                        </div>
                                </header>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Banner Wrapper -->
            <div id="banner-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">

                            <!-- Banner -->
                                <div id="banner" class="box">

                                    <div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="7u">
                                                <h2>Morbi ultrices ultrices sem, sed placerat tortor pulvinar sed. </h2>
                                                <p>Nullam nec nulla nisi. Nunc mauris mi, pharetra eu placerat vitae, luctus nec enim.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Footer Wrapper -->
            <div id="footer-wrapper">
                <footer id="footer" class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="3u">

                            <!-- Contact -->
                                <section class="widget-contact last">
                                    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/App4UBr" class="fa fa-twitter solo"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/App4UBr" class="fa fa-facebook solo"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p>Av. João, 1234<br />
                                    São Paulo, São Paulo<br />
                                    (11) 1234-1234</p>
                                </section>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <div id="copyright">
                                &copy; App4U Sistemas de Informação Ltda. All rights reserved. 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE-2-END**

Can anyone give a head up for me?
Cheers.

Comment: Please give us a sample of the code that's in (1) or (2).  Also, is the PHP script above the "ONLY" code in (3)?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Any errors? Blank page?

Comment: Show your HTML output, not your PHP. The problem is on the client.

Comment: it seems like path issues.

Comment: updated the post with the outputs and code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for all the advice, tried the three options suggestions that were offered, but what really made the trick was putting the "css" folder in the "php" folder.

So I think it's not a fancy move but got it going.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use relative paths.

Make sure in your css includes to specify relative file path with a `/`.

Non-relative: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/skin.css">`

Relative: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/skin.css">`

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
 include("../jude/updatecomplete.html");
```

And that is including an HTML file that has in it something like this:

```
 <LINK href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The HTML file has its reference to the CSS relative to its location.  But the PHP file is in a different location, so once the HTML file's contents are printed into the output of the PHP file, the browser cannot load the CSS file because the relative path is not correct based on the location of the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS doesn't work because your PHP script is in another directory from what the HTML you're including is. By doing so, the stylesheet your including in the HTML file does not have the correct paths. Try appending the stylesheet's paths with a `../`, like so:

`<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

and you will see that it starts working when calling the PHP script but not the HTML file directly.